# onChange not working with react Formsy

Tags: reactjs, formsy-react

I am using react formsy(https://github.com/formsy/formsy-react).
Following is my code, in this handleChange is not working.

If i use simple select then it works

I need to get value on change to get cities.

```
<SelectFormsy
   className="mb-16"
    name="state"
    label="state"
    value={state}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    >
      {stateReducer.state.map((s, idx) => (
             <MenuItem key={idx} value={s.stateName}>{s.stateName}</MenuItem>
       ))}
</SelectFormsy>


handleChange= (event) => {
    console.log(['state',event.target]);
    this.setState({stateId:event.target.value});
}
```

Comment: Please provide the whole React Component code.

Answer (score 0):

The SelectFormsy object will take the onChange function as a prop. Inside the SelectFormsy object you need to take that prop and call it.

ALL INSIDE SelectFormsy

```
<Select
    onChange={this.SOME_CHANGE_FUNCTION}
/>

changeValue = (event) => {
    if (this.props.onChange) {
        this.props.onChange(event)
    }
}
```

;